# Typesafe Slick 2.0.1-RC insert into database

Tags: slick, typesafe

I have problem when inserting into database. I use slick version 2.0.1-RC. I have used SourceCodeGenerator for generating source code. I have got this for table MAIN_TC_USER:

```
case class MainTcUserRow(id: Int, name: Option[String], surname: Option[String], username:           Option[String], password: Option[String]) 
/** GetResult implicit for fetching MainTcUserRow objects using plain SQL queries */
implicit def GetResultMainTcUserRow(implicit e0: GR[Int], e1: GR[Option[String]]):      GR[MainTcUserRow] = GR{
   prs => import prs._
   MainTcUserRow.tupled((<<[Int], <<?[String], <<?[String], <<?[String], <<?[String]))
}
/** Table description of table main_tc_user. Objects of this class serve as prototypes for rows   in queries. */
class MainTcUser(tag: Tag) extends Table[MainTcUserRow](tag, "main_tc_user") {
def * = (id, name, surname, username, password) <> (MainTcUserRow.tupled, MainTcUserRow.unapply)
/** Maps whole row to an option. Useful for outer joins. */
def ? = (id.?, name, surname, username, password).shaped.<>({r=>import r._; _1.map(_=> MainTcUserRow.tupled((_1.get, _2, _3, _4, _5)))}, (_:Any) =>  throw new Exception("Inserting into ? projection not supported."))

/** Database column id PrimaryKey */
val id: Column[Int] = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey)
/** Database column name  */
val name: Column[Option[String]] = column[Option[String]]("name")
/** Database column surname  */
val surname: Column[Option[String]] = column[Option[String]]("surname")
/** Database column username  */
val username: Column[Option[String]] = column[Option[String]]("username")
/** Database column password  */
val password: Column[Option[String]] = column[Option[String]]("password")
}
/** Collection-like TableQuery object for table MainTcUser */
lazy val MainTcUser = new TableQuery(tag => new MainTcUser(tag))
```

I have tried to insert into MainTcUser table

```
new DBConnection(Tables.profile).connect.withSession{
  implicit session =>

    Tables.MainTcUser += user        
}
```

or

```
new DBConnection(Tables.profile).connect.withSession{
  implicit session =>

    Tables.MainTcUser.map(s => s) += user        
}
```

In both cases I've got error: 
Multiple markers at this line
    - value += is not a member of 
     scala.slick.lifted.TableQuery[com.bsi.xpay.Tables.MainTcUser]
    - value += is not a member of 
     scala.slick.lifted.TableQuery[com.bsi.xpay.Tables.MainTcUser]

Thanks for any help

Comment: This may be a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22288836/cant-access-delete-method-on-slick-query

Are you import .simple._? Are you using play-slick? I'll have to check on its cake pattern example. There may be something wrong with it.

Comment: Cross posted here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/scalaquery/G1Bc1flxcAE/bMUGrYsDi0gJ

Comment: Cvogt you were right. That import was missing. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably forgot to import `.simple._` from you driver.

If that's not it also see [Can't access delete method on Slick query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22288836/cant-access-delete-method-on-slick-query)  which is related.